# How do I inject a dateFormatter servide into a service class named MyService?

Tags: dependency-injection

I have a service class declared like this:

```
 class MyService implements MyServiceInterface {
```

I want to get rid of a (working) call to a the `static \Drupal::service('date.formatter')` function and replace with a injected call to `$this->dateFormatter`.

I am looking at the most upvoted answer to this question: [Make a custom date formatter for view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/222963/12076).

It suggests that you can output a custom formatted timestamp like this:

```
$now = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime();
$currenttime = $this->dateFormatter->format($now, 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i');
```

However, this does not work for me. It uses an injected call to the [public function DateFormatter::format](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DateFormatter.php/function/DateFormatter%3A%3Aformat/10), and the upvoted answer does not explain how to set up the class where it is used to inject this service. This produces a WSOD on my site. The cause is obviously that `dateFormatter` has not been initialized.

As noted, I know that *using* a static call works:

```
$now = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime();
$currenttime = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($now, 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i');
```

I have a *rough* idea bout how to set up a service class to initialize an injected service. I.e. I *think* to be able to use it, I need to do at least three things:

1. Declare the injected service as an argument in `myservice.services.yml`.
2. Declare the injected property as a `$protected` variable.
3. Initialize it in the class' contructor.

But I am not even sure if this is correct. And the details eludes me. For example: How do I discover what name to include in `myservice.services.yml`?

Any guidance will be appreciated.

PS: I have studied this answer: [How do I inject services in a service](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/226200/12076), but I don't understand how it applies to my question.

It has been suggested that [Inject a class as dependecy injection in a service](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/317368/12076) is a duplicate. The accepted answer to that question is *not* about the `@date.formatter` service that is the subject of my question, and it does not mention using `autowire` to solve the problem. (Which I learned how to use in the answer I now have accepted.)

Comment: A brief comment explaining *why* you downvote this question would be appreciated. I am open to improving it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inject a class as depency injection in a service](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/317368/inject-a-class-as-depency-injection-in-a-service)

Comment: No, the answer does not address the use case where the service already exists, as is the case with the `@date.formatter` service, so there is no need to create a factory for it. It is an answer for a different use case.

Comment: The linked post is how to do it - factories aren’t relevant here, date formatter is a singleton service. These days you can also autowire the arguments in services.yml instead of specifying them if you’d prefer. I haven’t voted but I’m guessing the downvotes are because this is covered pretty exhaustively on this site already and the greater net at large

Comment: I now have received an answer introducing the autowire feature. That is not mentioned in the linked post that is supposed to be a duplicate of this one.

Comment: Autowiring is optional, a newer feature - the meat of the question is definitely a duplicate. This is all laid out  with examples in [the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8#s-defining-your-own-services), that’s usually the best place to start when confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*But I am not even sure if this is correct. And the details eludes me. For example: How do I discover what name to include in myservice.services.yml?*

Now that Drupal 9 is end of life you no longer need to do that. Replace the argument list with the autowire option:

*mymodule.services.yml*

```
services:
  mymodule.my_service:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\MyService
    autowire: true
```

and in the service class:

```
  /**
   * The date formatter.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatterInterface
   */
  protected $dateFormatter;

  /**
   * Constructs \Drupal\mymodule\MyService
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatterInterface $date_formatter
   *   The date formatter.
   */
  public function __construct(DateFormatterInterface $date_formatter) {
    $this->dateFormatter = $date_formatter;
  }
```

So to discover the service you only need the interface DateFormatterInterface. Use autocomplete and the IDE will automatically add a use statement at the top:

```
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatterInterface;
```

See the change record: [Core services provide aliases for autowiring](https://www.drupal.org/node/3323122)